Shortcut loops not executed properly
In IOS Shortcut, I've set up a loop whose time duration is roughly 120 seconds. The loop will repeat itself for 10 times. Inside the loop, my device will read "1000" to trigger a certain sequence of gestures through voice control. However, if I left my device unattended, it will not read anymore. Is there any possible reason behind this?
ps: I've tried to tap my screen from time to time in one loop. Then Shortcut will proceed to the next loop. However if I just leave it there, it will not repeat.
